# SVN error after first checkout

Tags: svn, revert, svn-checkout

After the first check out, I use "svn status", it show the strange error (2 lines with the same content):

```
!       W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/ソースコード_20110715.zip
!       W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/ソースコード_20110715.zip
```

Then I try to revert:

```
svn revert -R .
```

it shows the error:

```
svn: Error restoring text for 'trunk/W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/ソースコード_20110715.zip'
```

I tried to re-checkout many times, the error occurred similarly .I don't understand why after the first checkout, there's a error. How can I fix it?

Thank you!

EDIT:
(as MattL's answer)
If I use:

```
svn remove W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/ソースコード_20110715.zip
```

then the error shows as:

```
!       W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/ソースコード_20110715.zip
D       W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/ソースコード_20110715.zip
```

I still can not perform any revert, update, commit on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
svn remove W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/ソースコード_20110715.zip
svn update
svn commit
```

It appears that file was under version control, but svn can no longer find it. 'svn remove' should remove the file from version control, and svn will no longer care about it.

Comment: Try `svn remove W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/*`. This will remove all the files in that current directory from version control. You will then need to `svn add W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/*` to put all the files in that directory back under version control.

Answer (score 0):

You may have better luck with

```
svn remove W_DELIVERABLES/20110715/ソースコード_20110715.zip --force
```

The --force will, as it says, force the operation to execute, you can apply it to the folder so all files under it get deleted.

Comment: maybe the MattL sugestion of removing everything on folder, combined with the --force that I told you may work...